# Should I care about the difference between main thread and UI thread in Lollipop and beyond?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-5.0-lollipop

Before Lollipop, life was easy. You had a `main thread` - sometimes also called `UI thread` - in which all GUI stuff was done (and which you avoided under all circumstances for long-running operations to avoid any kind of hiccup), and you had your `background threads` where you did exactly this long-running stuff.

Now in Lollipop and later versions of Android, IIRC the term `UI thread` seems to point the user to the new `RenderThread`, a thread that is for example used to animate the ripples, hero elements between activities or any other kind of animation that needs to happen while the main thread processes input events or is busy creating new stuff for you in the background.

With Android Studio 1.3 all three thread types now got their own annotation, to denote that a particular piece of code should run on this particular thread. For me the question now is: Should I as app developer care to run *anything* on the `UIThread`, i.e. `RenderThread`, and as such ever use `@UIThread` in my application?

Comment: check the @UIThread generated code, you can find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember on Chet Haase's presentation of `RenderThread` from the last year's Google IO. His statement was, that in first place we have to continue with `MainThread` as before. `RenderThread` is to be used for animations only. For instance, if we have a method like `onDrawFrame()` drawing animation at smooth 60 fps, we should rather call it in `RenderThread`, because `MainThread` can be slowed down by application logic or other stuff.

Back to your question. I would say use `MainThread` as before. If you experience some performance issues with animations, then try to move drawing parts of your code to `RendererThread`.

Answer (score 3):

The `UIThread` is still the main thread of execution for your application. While `RenderThread` is just a support processing thread to help with your application when there are delays in your main UI thread. As quoted from developer.android.com:

"`RenderThread` is a new system-managed processing thread that keeps animations smooth even when there are delays in the main UI thread."

For your question, should you care to run anything on the `UIThread`? The answer is yes, should you use `RenderThread` instead? If possible, yes.